# NLog Filter NetSparker Scan

Tags: .net, .net-core, razor-pages, nlog

Our company routinely runs a security scan on our public website using NetSparker. Our current site uses Elmah and we have a rule to filter out the exceptions/errors encountered when the scan runs (see below). We are about to deploy an update to the site using .Net Core Razor Pages and NLog for logging. I'm having troubles figuring out how to accomplish this task and I have spent a bunch of time looking for similar articles related to this. Any help is appreciated.

Elmah Filter:

```
<regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['HTTP_X_SCANNER']" pattern=".*Netsparker.*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Netsparker always sends a request header of X-Scanner and the value of this header is Netsparker. [Using the aspnet-request-headers variable available in nlog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/473) you can [create a filter](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Filter#extensibility) in the email target. Here's what the filter looks like:

```
    <!--Send emails when an error is encountered.-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="email">
      <filters>
        <when condition="contains('${aspnet-request-headers:HeaderNames=X-Scanner}', 'Netsparker')" action="Ignore" />
        <when condition="contains('${aspnet-request-headers:HeaderNames=user-agent}', 'bots')" action="Ignore" />
      </filters>
    </logger>
```

You'll notice I also added a filter when the user-agent contains the word bots.